# Compilation error in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this message in my asp.net page.

Any suggestions to resolve this will be greatly appreciated. Thx.

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  using System;
Line 2:  using System.Data;
Line 3:  using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

The aspx code is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The C# code is:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


class SqlConnectionDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = SqlConnection("Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=JobSearchManager;Integrated Security = SSPI");
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Agency", conn);
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader;
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (rdr != null)
            {
                rdr.Close();
            }
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try reading the "Compiler Error Message" out loud. And then look at your class declaration.

Comment: Can you add the code of your code-behind file, _Default.aspx.cs?

Comment: Ok, so I deleted my solution and created a whole new web project. IT WORKS !! (Error Free). THANKS ALL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your aspx code says `Inherits="_Default"` but your class is called `SqlConnectionDemo`. These need to match.

Answer (score 1):

Your C# code is not the code behind for that web page (or any web page). It should have something like this at the beginning of the class:

```
class _Default : System.Web.Page {
```

Your class has a Main method, as if it was from a console application instead. Have you pasted a database example over the original code behind class?

Comment: Not quite. Actually I trying to build my first C# 2008 aspx page. I copied this example from a website. Guess the example needs some tweeking.

Comment: @LearningCSharp: I see. Either you mixed up the examples, or you should look for better ones.

Comment: Its one of those quikie examples that use the console.writeline methods. I hate console.writeline, so I tried to convert it into a web interface. Everyone here contributed to the solution. Wish I could give all a green check mark. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a class file named "Default.aspx.cs" that looks like this?

```
using System;

namespace YourApplicationName
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I do have a class named Default.aspx.cs that inherits off this page